# Getting specific line from Cash Flow

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to get data from Cash Flow with [getFinancials](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getFinancials.html) function in R.

```
library(quantmod)
s <- c("AAPL","GOOG","IBM","GS","AMZN","GE")
fin <- lapply(s, getFinancials, auto.assign=FALSE)
names(fin) <- s
```

But when I try to get a specific line with

```
fin$AAPL$CF$A["Cash from Operating Activities"]
fin$AAPL$CF$A["Capital Expenditures"]
```

I get a NA return. How can I get these specific lines from the Cash Flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `fin$AAPL$CF$A` is a matrix, you need a comma after the name because you are asking for a **row** name.  Without a comma you are asking for a vector element named "Cash from Operating Activities", and since we have a matrix the individual elements are not named.

```
class(fin$AAPL$CF$A)
# [1] "matrix"
"Cash from Operating Activities" %in% rownames(fin$AAPL$CF$A)
# [1] TRUE

## no comma - NA because "Cash from Operating Activities" is not a named vector element
fin$AAPL$CF$A["Cash from Operating Activities"]
# [1] NA
```

This can be more easily illustrated with

```
x <- 1
x["x"]
# [1] NA
```

Since `x` has no named element `"x"`, we get NA.  You want the following.

```
## with comma - asking for the row "Cash from Operating Activities"
fin$AAPL$CF$A["Cash from Operating Activities", ]
# 2014-09-27 2013-09-28 2012-09-29 2011-09-24 
#      59713      53666      50856      37529
```

Since these are matrices, rows are requested on the left side of the comma, columns on the right, and single named elements with no comma.